# How to change the default sort by some column in Postgres 10.2?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I'm getting a list of blog posts from Postgres

```sql
select id, post_priority, publish_start
from posts
where email = 'someuser@gmail.com'
ORDER BY publish_start DESC
```

If there are many articles publishes the same date, the list is going wrong.

When i retrieved from Postgres 10.2 (server Ubuntu)

```
  id  | title |    post_priority     | publish_start
------+-------+----------------------+----------------
 1001 | A...  | 1                    | 2019-09-05
 1002 | B...  | 2                    | 2019-09-05
```

And it's different when I retrieved from my dev machine - Postgres 11 (MacOS)

```
  id  | title |    post_priority     | publish_start
------+-------+----------------------+----------------
 1002 | B...  | 2                    | 2019-09-05
 1001 | A...  | 1                    | 2019-09-05
```

I know I just only need to add one more column to order in the query. But I still wonder what decided the default sort when publish_start dates are the same for all articles? How to change/config that default column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There is no such thing as a default sort order.

If two (or more) rows have the same value for the columns specified in the `order by` the ordering of those rose is undefined.

The **only** way to get a stable and guaranteed sort order is to add `post_priority` to the `order by` columns.

Comment: thank you for confirming that. But I'm still curious why 1 query returns 2 different results. Both are not sorted, so why they don't have the same order? ^^

Comment: @Davuz: because the database is free to return the rows in any order it wants. This can be influenced by the execution plan, the physical layout of the rows on disk, concurrent queries, the default collation, the number of update/delete/insert operations and many other factors.